# How to interpret basic output from a regression analysis?

Tags: regression, interpretation

I have been trying to interpret the results below, but I am finding it difficult. I wonder if someone could help me. All answers highly appreciated.

> Number of obs = 30
>   F( 2, 27) = 19.73
>   Prob > F = 0.0000
>   R-squared = 0.5937
>   Adj R-squared = 0.5637

Comment: It's hard to do this without knowing the context of the analysis. What were the dependent and independent variables? What model was run? From the F, it looks like an ANOVA with 3 groups

Comment: What textbooks, handbooks, software manuals, or other learning resources have you consulted?

Answer (score 2):

There are few introduction about the variables and results (and requirement for regression also). However, from the short results posted we can (hardly) say:
i) There exists dependency between the two variables. (p-value = 0.000)
ii) The 59.37% of the variability of the Dependent variable is explained by the variation on the Independent variable (we don't know the labels).

(This is a light-answer according to the (fast)question ;)

Answer (score 1):

F(x,y) = Z

x: Numerator degrees of freedom
y: Denominator degrees of freedom
z: Value of the F-statistic

That can be used to back-calculate (or look up in a table) whether or not your finding is significant at any arbitrary significance threshold.

You may find [this to be a useful resource](http://www.socr.ucla.edu/Applets.dir/F_Table.html).