# Interpreting the results of an analysis

Tags: f-test

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to interpret basic output from a regression analysis?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16567/how-to-interpret-basic-output-from-a-regression-analysis)

I am wondering what does the following stand for: F( 2, 27) = 19.73. As far as I understand his has to do with the F-test. I don't know how to interpret this.

Could someone please advice me.