# When is the determinant of a covariance matrix is 0?

Tags: covariance, independence

Any covariance matrix $A$ must be non-negative definite or semi-positive definite. This means that its deteraminant should always $|A|\ge0$.
In case $|A|=0$, what would happen? or what does this mean for the dependence of the corresponding random variables?

Million thanks for your answers and hints

Comment: There's a linear combination of variables which is constant.

Comment: For example [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/70910/3277) answer covers it.