# Priors and multi-collinearity in regression analysis

Tags: regression, anova, lasso, multicollinearity, ridge-regression

I understand why ridge regression (equivalent to using a Gaussian prior on the coefficients in a Bayesian setting) [works well](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104779/why-does-ridge-regression-work-well-in-the-presence-of-multicollinearity) in the presence of multi-collinearity, but couldn't one argue that **other** shrinking **priors** would also help? (e.g. say a Laplace prior, as in LASSO).

Moreover, if OLS is effectively equivalent to using a **uniform prior** (with a Gaussian likelihood), what type of **priors** can arguably with multi-collinearity? In other words, what **conditions** does a **prior** have to have to help with multi-collinearity?

Comment: In terms of shrinkage and multicollinearity, elastic net regression gives you the benefits of LASSO and ridge regression at the cost of an additional hyperparameter.

Comment: Thanks @Sycorax I understand one can obviously combine both with Elastic Net. I am particularly interested in the relationship these priors have with multi-collinearity (I have updated the OP to clarify this point).

Comment: If I understand correctly, it seems like any unimodal prior may work.  All else equal, the selected fit would be the one which is most probable under the prior.