# Regression modelling with mixed data set: categorical and numerical predictor variables

Tags: regression, categorical-data, continuous-data

There are thirteen predictor variables which are a combination of 8 continuous, 4 binary and 1 categorical variables. The dependent variable is again categorical. I understand that I need to use dummy coding for binary and categorical variables.

How should I model the dependent variable with respect to predictor variables? Which regression model can be used?

Comment: The standard regression model in these cases is called : [multinomial logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression). To my knowledge implementations of it can be found in almost all major packages (eg. R, MATLAB, SAS, etc.)

Comment: The fact that you have both categorical and numerical predictors is of no consequence, with a suitable response variable, multiple regression could deal with both. However, the fact that the response is categorical is crucial in determining what kinds of analyses may be suitable.

Comment: I tried looking for multinominal logistic regression in R. Initially, I modified my dataset using, mlm <- mlogit.data(diffdata, varying = NULL, choice = "D", shape = "wide") , model.1 <- mlogit (D ~ T5 + T6 + KC + (1|T1) + (1|T2) + (1|T3) + (1|T4) + (1|S2) + (1|S3) + (1|S4) + (1|S5), data = mlm, reflevel = "easy"), I am getting following error, Error in solve.default(H, g[!fixed]) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[3,3] = 0

Comment: are your columns independent? see  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70899/what-correlation-makes-a-matrix-singular-and-what-are-implications-of-singularit