# Defining NULL group for dummy variables

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data

I am quite new in R and am on a stage of running a regression model there.
The approach we have chosen is linear regression with dummy variables.
As far as my knowledge and experience go when using dummies one should choose a null interval - class(group) within a variable that will receive 0 points. This should help tackle the multicollinearity.

My question is - how do we set (if we can) the null interval?
I reviewed the "dummies" package but did not see an option there.

Thanks,
N

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "null interval" here. You might find the thread [Understanding Dummy Variable Creation in GLM](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94010/understanding-dummy-manual-or-automated-variable-creation-in-glm) useful?

Comment: The question is not about statistics but about R programming. Anyway you might check the "relevel" command in R. There you can choose the reference category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be asking "how do I choose which is the baseline group?" (the group that is subsumed into the intercept term). In R, if you have a factor, the default baseline is the first level in the factor.

You can change which level is the first easily with `relevel` (see `?relevel`, particularly the examples at the bottom), or you can completely reorder the factor, either via `reorder` or by calling `factor` on the factor with the newly ordered levels respecified.

(You may also be able to do something useful with the `contrast` function and some of the related functions.)

With non-large data sets, I find myself using `factor` to reorder more often lately.

Comment: Thanks for that answer! And yes... I meant - reference group! It may not be popular but I have ofter refer to it as the null group (cause all the dummies are 0). Cheers!

Comment: "null group" would be reasonably well understood. However, "null interval" is not; you wouldn't typically refer to a group as an interval. [Unless,... hmm ... are you splitting up a continuous variable? Generally speaking that's a bad idea.]